# Is any finite set necessarily closed and compact?

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a finite set, then $X$ is compact since any finite set is compact. $X$ is closed since its complement $\emptyset$ is open (in any topology on $X$).

Something wrong?

Comment: Do you mean closed in the topology of $X$ or is $X\subset Y$ where $Y$ is a topological space?

Comment: @DominicMIchaelis I meant closed in the topology of $X$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even more: any topology on a finite set has only finitely many open sets! Thus every open cover *is* a finite cover.

Even even more: any finite set has only finitely many subsets, so every cover is a finite cover.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, nothing's wrong. Any topological space whatsoever is closed, considered as a subset of itself, and any finite topological space is compact.

Answer (score 2):

Why you mention that $X$ is closed? For compactness you don't need that $X$ is closed, in non hausdorff spaces compact subsets of topological spaces aren't close in general.

From the definition of a topology you know that $X$ is open and closed.