# Metric: $X$ is compact if $X$ is finite

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

i am having again some maths problems i don't understand.
Unfortunately, in this case, i don't have even an idea how to start with :-/

This is my Problem:

Let $X$ a non-empty set. We define a metric $d$ on $X$ with $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}1 & x \neq y\\0 & x = y\end{cases}$$

How can i show that $X$ is compact if $X$ is finite?

Is this maybe possible with example of sets? If i am not totally wrong the metric should be a discrete metric. Right? I have no idea...

Comment: What's your definition of compact?

Comment: That is the disrete metric, right? Shouldn't it be x=y and x \neq y instead of x=0 and x \neq 0?

Comment: @AdriánNaranjo i checked this right after i posted. It is the discrete metric and this should be correct

Comment: @hukachaka are you sure about that? $0$ might not be an element of $X$ for example...

Comment: @AndresMejia i am such an idiot. It was a long day today. Now it should be fine :-)

Comment: @quasi This is our definition i translated: A subset A of a metric space is compact, if each sequence in A has a convergent subsequence, of which limit is in A.

Comment: @hukachaka just for info and you might see it later on anyway, sometimes that's called sequential compactness, and it turns out to be equivalent to other definitions such as the one using covers in andres answer for metric spaces

Comment: Thank you all. I think i am going to let digest everything and post my solution tomorrow right here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ be any cover of $X$. Let $x_1 \in X$. Then there exists some $U_{\alpha}$ that contains $x_1$ by definition. Continue in this way for all $x_{i} \in X$. You will get a family of $U_{\alpha_i}$ that is finite by assumption.

This procedure has nothing to do with the metric, and that is because [every topology on a finite set makes it compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326166/is-any-finite-set-necessarily-closed-and-compact).

---

Using your definition from the comments: If you have only finitely many elements in $X$,, while  the sequence has infinitely many elements of $X$, one among them must occur infinitely many times. What can you construct by knowing this?

Comment: @AndresMeija ok thank you for this hint. I will try to solve this and post it here when i have something presentable. I had something wrong in my first post. The discrete metric was not right. I still can use this, right?

Comment: @hukachaka I added some comments using the appropriate definition of compactness.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a definition of compactness in terms of sequences (rather than open covers), I suggest showing that if all the terms in a sequence are in a finite set $X$, then there is a subsequence all of whose terms are the same, i.e., a constant sequence.  Then show (if you don't already have this result) that every constant sequence in a metric space converges.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ is finite, $X = \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ say, an infinite sequence of elements of $X$ can't have only finitely many of each of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

It follow that at least one of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, must occur infinitely often in the sequence.

Thus the sequence has an infinite subsequence which is *constant*, hence converges to that constant.

Therefore (using your definition), $X$ is compact.